# Get/Set file comment in OSX from python3?

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I've searched both SE and the web, but haven't found an answer to this.

Is it possible to get/set a file comment on OSX (Sierra) in python3? I guess more accurately — is it possible to do so directly, without having to invoke mdls?

Context: I have a list of transient files that have comments on them. The files come and go, but when the come back, they'll have the same filename. I want to preserve the comments so I can re-put the comment on the files if the files are deleted and re-added. I'm going to create a python script that would output a list of file,comments, and another script that would read that list and put the comments on the associated files.

I can do everything except the actual getting/setting of the comment, and I haven't been able to find anything on if that can be done directly from python3, and if so, how.

Thanks!